# Поочередная смена картинок в разных блоках

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачку.
Есть 3 блока, в каждом из блоков есть изображения. Нужно, чтобы изображения выводились поочередно.

У меня получается вывести первые изображения с каждого блока поочередно, но на следующей волне смены картинок, они идут вразнобой.

HTML:

```
    <div id="slideshow-1" class="js_multiSlide">
        <a href="/link-1.html">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/gallery-index/1/1.jpg" alt="image" class="active" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/gallery-index/1/2.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/gallery-index/1/3.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="slideshow-2" class="js_multiSlide">
        <a href="/link-2.html">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/gallery-index/2/1.jpg" alt="image" class="active" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/gallery-index/2/2.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/gallery-index/2/3.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </div>


    <div id="slideshow-3" class="js_multiSlide">
        <a href="/link-3.html">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/gallery-index/3/1.jpg" alt="image" class="active" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/gallery-index/3/2.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/gallery-index/3/3.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow-1 img.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow-1 img:last');
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow-1 img:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({opacity: 0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}, 2000);

setInterval(function() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow-2 img.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow-2 img:last');
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow-2 img:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({opacity: 0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}, 3000);


setInterval(function() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow-3 img.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow-3 img:last');
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow-3 img:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({opacity: 0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться примером [последовательных вызовов функций](http://habrahabr.ru/post/134823/), что гарантирует очередность выполнения анимации

---

UPD: [набросал простой пример с помощью wait и функции:](https://jsfiddle.net/jmsuL105/)

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('here');

      wait = function(first) {
        return new(function() {
          var self = this;

          var callback = function() {
            var args;
            if (self.deferred.length) {
              args = [].slice.call(arguments);
              args.unshift(callback);
              self.deferred[0].apply(self, args);
              self.deferred.shift();
            }
          };

          this.wait = function(run) {
            this.deferred.push(run);
            return self;
          };

          this.deferred = [];

          first(callback);
        });
      };

      wait(function(runNext) {
        log('step-1');
        setTimeout(function() {
          showImg();
          runNext();
        }, 1000);

      }).wait(function(runNext) {
        log('step-2');
        setTimeout(function() {
          showImg();
          runNext();
        }, 1000);
      }).wait(function(runNext) {
        log('step-3');
        setTimeout(function() {
          showImg()
        }, 1000);
      }).wait(function() {
        log('end');
      });
    });

    function showImg() {
      $('#wrapper .js_multiSlide').each(function() {
        var img = $(this).find('img').not('.active').first();
        if (img.length)
          img.css({
            opacity: 0
          }).addClass('active').animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, 1000, function() {});
      });
    }

    function log(str) {
      console.log(str);
    }
```

```css
    .js_multiSlide img {
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="slideshow-1" class="js_multiSlide">
    <a href="/link-1.html">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="http://vestacp.com/images/logo.png" alt="image" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://vestacp.com/images/logo.png" alt="image" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://vestacp.com/images/logo.png" alt="image" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="slideshow-2" class="js_multiSlide">
    <a href="/link-2.html">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="http://vestacp.com/images/logo.png" alt="image" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://vestacp.com/images/logo.png" alt="image" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://vestacp.com/images/logo.png" alt="image" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="slideshow-3" class="js_multiSlide">
    <a href="/link-3.html">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="http://vestacp.com/images/logo.png" alt="image" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://vestacp.com/images/logo.png" alt="image" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://vestacp.com/images/logo.png" alt="image" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Задолбусь .wait прописывать. Может есть другие варианты?

Comment: Собственно тут надо прописать wait 3 раза всего. Обернуть эти три блока, вместо setInterval -> .wait

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте предлагаемое решение в тело вашего ответа (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ваш ответ станет бесполезен).

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил решение